# MySQL Do multiple counts with different WHERE clause and seeing the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get from my orders table: the number of orders each customer has placed within a week, then do another count for the next week, then again, and again, etc.

I am using COUNT but it keeps bringing back an empty result.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT `uid`, (SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `orders` WHERE `order_timestamp` > '1476707688' and `order_timestamp` < '1476189288') as 'number1',
       (SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `orders` WHERE `order_timestamp` > '1476189288' and `order_timestamp` < '1475584488') as 'number2',
       (SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `orders` WHERE `order_timestamp` > '1475584488' and `order_timestamp` < '1474979688') as 'number3'
FROM `orders` ORDER BY `uid` ASC
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I know that there are multiple orders in a week from multiple customers.

How do you do that query?
A query that will bring back the number of orders a customer has made in that time period?

Cheers,

Comment: `order_timestamp` > '1475584488' and `order_timestamp` < '1474979688'` are you sure this will return a value? can something be **more than 1475...** and **less than 1474...** ?

Comment: Yeah, that was a rookie error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT `uid`,
       SUM(`order_timestamp` > '1476707688' and `order_timestamp` < '1476189288') as number1,
       SUM(`order_timestamp` > '1476189288' and `order_timestamp` < '1475584488') as number2,
       SUM(`order_timestamp` > '1475584488' and `order_timestamp` < '1474979688') as number3
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `uid` ASC;
```

Note:  this aggregates by `uid`, so there will be one row per `uid` rather than per order.  That seems like the sensible thing to do.

Comment: This is the one I want! Thanks mate. Also, I originally messed up the greater than, less than... so its opposite. :)
But this brings back the result I need. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try as follow?

```
SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY uid DESC;        
SELECT * FROM {table}WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY uid DESC;
SELECT * FROM {table}WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY uid DESC;
```

Comment: Can you please be more precise? What's your intention and what issues are you facing?